# The given path's format is not supported

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am getting the following error while uploading the file from my local drive.

> The given path's format is not supported.

The code is given.
Please tell me what changes I have to make.

```
 string file0 = MapPathReverse(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);// Get virtual path
    string conversationFileSource = Server.MapPath(file0);
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(conversationFileSource);
```

Comment: What is the `MapPathReverse()` function doing? Can you post its code?

Comment: MapPathReverse is a method to get virtual path.

Comment: public static string MapPathReverse(string fullServerPath)
    {
        return @"~\" + fullServerPath.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, String.Empty);
    }

Comment: I want to upload a file and use its full path to access that file. I need its full path so that I can read that file and proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the input stream of the uploaded file:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
{
    ...
}
```

If you want to save the uploaded file on some folder on your server:

```
var uploadsFolder = Server.MapPath("~/uploads");
var file = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(file);
```